# Display SVN externals in PhpStorm

Tags: svn, phpstorm, svn-externals

Is it possible to see the SVN externals in PhpStorm? Like in Eclipse there is a red arrow that marks the external folder.

And yes I know that I can get the overview of the properties.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that currently there's no such a way. Please vote:
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-85163